# Wkwebview implementation in cordova based applications

Tags: ios, cordova, wkwebview

How to implement WKWebView in hybrid application.I am using cordova 2.7.0.Do i need to wait for new cordova version to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The Cordova team is currently working on a bridge to implement WKWebView use in a later release, that, yes, we will have to wait for. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7043

Answer (score 0):

In the meanwhile, you can use this plugin: 
https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-wkwebview